# Invalid command for interaction application

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I register an SlashCommand... but it answered "Invalid command for interaction application" Can somebody help...

```
 @Override
    public void onSlashCommand(SlashCommandEvent event) {

        if (event.getName().equals("login")) {

            EmbedBuilder buil = new EmbedBuilder();
            buil.setColor(Color.RED);
            buil.appendDescription("Du hast deinen DiscordAccount noch nicht mit dem TurnierSystem verknüpft... Benutze ?connect um die Accounts zu verknüpfen.");
            buil.setAuthor("TurnierSystem");
            buil.setTitle("Discord Login (Fehler)");

           event.replyEmbeds(buil.build()).queue();

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This response means that the Discord client tried to use an old version of the command that it had cached. If you simply retype the command, it should use the updated command instead.

The cause of this behavior is from calling `upsertCommand` when you start your bot. This will *replace* the existing command and make the client cache invalid.

You can use `updateCommands().addCommands(allOfYourCommands).queue()` instead, to prevent this from happening. However, keep in mind you need to put all your commands in `addCommands(...)`, not just one at a time!

Comment: If I use "event.replay("test").queue();" then it works but but when I take "event.replyEmbeds(buil.build()).queue();" it doesn't work again

Comment: Nevermind i kicked the Bot and now it works.... Thanks @Minn